# Ruby on rails: Need to pass drop down ID/value back to the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

I'm new to RoR and I'm trying to pass the drop down id selected by the user back to the controller to load a page specific to a business. I have a simple DB listing ten businesses which loads fine but when I select an option I'm getting this error: **No route matches [POST] "/businesses/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10"**

Can I get the action value to be dynamic for the form? What are some options?

Controller: businesses_controller.rb

```
  def home
    @business_dd = Business.find(:all)
  end

  def update
    @business = Business.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to :action => "show", :id => @business
  end

  def show
    @business_dd = Business.find(:all)
    @business = Business.find(params[:id])
  end
```

View: _header.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :business, :url => business_path(@business_dd) do |f| %>               
        <%= f.select(:id, options_for_select(
        @business_dd.map{ |f| [f.name, f.id]}), 
        :include_blank => 'Please select') %>
        <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
    <% end %>
```

HTML generated for the drop down:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/businesses/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="FS7sYiq8NicsKfnUwzTTHpobtA180qOjcAOnuWNONPc=" /></div>                
<select id="business_id" name="business[id]"><option value="">Please select</option>
<option value="1">Business1</option>
<option value="2">Business2</option>
<option value="3">Business3</option>
<option value="4">Business4</option>
<option value="5">Business5</option>
<option value="6">Business6</option>
<option value="7">Business7</option>
<option value="8">Business8</option>
<option value="9">Business9</option>
<option value="10">Business10</option></select>
<input name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Routes:

```
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
  businesses GET    /businesses(.:format)          businesses#index
             POST   /businesses(.:format)          businesses#create
new_business GET    /businesses/new(.:format)      businesses#new
edit_business GET    /businesses/:id/edit(.:format) businesses#edit
    business GET    /businesses/:id(.:format)      businesses#show
             PATCH  /businesses/:id(.:format)      businesses#update
             PUT    /businesses/:id(.:format)      businesses#update
             DELETE /businesses/:id(.:format)      businesses#destroy
        root GET    /                              businesses#home
      update GET    /update(.:format)              businesses#update
```

Answer (score 0):

in routes.rb

```
resources :businesses, only: [:allowed, :actions, :here]
```

then it is better to include action `new` in controller

```
def new
  @business = Business.new
end
```

and use it with view `new.html.erb` (not `home.html.erb`) to render form to submit:

```
<%= form_for @business do |f| %>  
  ...
```

Comment: I was actually able to do it be changing the way I populate the drop down: `<%= form_tag(new_business_path, method: 'get') do |f| %>
   <%= select_tag(:id, 
   options_for_select(Business.find(:all).map{ |f| [f.name, f.id]}), 
    :prompt => "Select Venue") %>
   <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
  <% end %>`

Comment: there is always several ways to solve any issue. if you use `new_business_path` then you created action `new`. your question has my answer. if you think your answer is better - you can add it and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to simplify the drop down and get the path to work:

```
<%= form_tag(new_business_path, method: 'get') do |f| %> 
   <%= select_tag(:id, 
   options_for_select(Business.find(:all).map{ |f| [f.name, f.id]}), :prompt => "Select Venue") %> 
   <%= submit_tag "Submit" %> 
<% end %>
```